# Changing ssh terminal background colour creates remote directory as side-effect when running Ansible

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, ansible

In `~/.ssh/config` I've added a [LocalCommand](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/) that changes my terminal background to a nice raspberry colour:

```
Host raspberrypi.local
    LocalCommand printf '\033]11;#220505\007'

Host *
    PermitLocalCommand yes
```

then when I log out, a couple of entries in my `.bashrc` file restore the background colour:

```bsh
colorsh() {
        \ssh $*     # use `command ssh`, `\ssh` or "ssh" to ignore alias; or infinite loop
        printf '\033]11;#050505\007'
}

alias ssh='colorsh'
```

Thanks to [Brian Gilbert](http://bryangilbert.com/post/etc/term/dynamic-ssh-terminal-background-colors/) for the idea.

However, when I run a simple Ansible playbook it creates a directory called `''$'\033'']11'` with a file called `AnsiballZ_setup.py` inside it.

Removing the `LocalCommand` in my ssh config file solves the problem but then I lose my colours. Obviously Ansible is using ssh to communicate to my pi, here's the `inventory` file:

```yaml
local:
    hosts:
        localhost 
    vars:
        ansible_connection: local
pi:
    hosts:
        raspberrypi.local
    vars:
        ansible_user: pi
        ansible_connection: ssh
```

Any ideas what's happening when Ansible uses ssh which causes the LocalCommand to have this effect?

I did try putting the printf command into my .bashrc wrapper function but that didn't quite work the way I wanted so am looking for other workarounds.

- Host: Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2
- Client: Raspberry Pi OS

Edit: I tried prepending a semi-colon to the printf string `';\033]11;#220505\007'` and that worked with the minimal side of seeing the semi-colon appear in the welcome message when connecting via ssh. However, the connection would fail on the first attempt with the error:

> fatal: [raspberrypi.local]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in "/tmp". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p "`echo ;\u001b]11;#220505\u0007/home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1614707093.517033-188023619558789`" && echo ansible-tmp-1614707093.517033-188023619558789="`echo ;\u001b]11;#220505\u0007/home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1614707093.517033-188023619558789`" ), exited with result 1", "unreachable": true}

If Ansible commands are being piped through printf I think I'll have problems whatever string I use. For example I tried `'weird'` as the string and ended up with a directory struture `weird/home/pi`.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but no solution. :(

Comment: Having run into another problem where my prompt wasn't lining up properly when going through the history, it might be an idea to try wrapping the print statement with `\[  \]`